# angular 6 ag-grid enterprise 19.0.0

Tags: ag-grid

I'm trying to import features available under enterprise license into my angular 6 app, but it seems ag-grid doesn't see license key.

I have already imported ag-grid and ag-grid-community and it works fine, but there are some problems with enterprise licensed features.

Yesterday I got trial license for 2 month;
I downloaded package ag-grid-enterprise via npm and imported LicenseManager component (before bootstraping app):

import { LicenseManager } from 'ag-grid-enterprise';
LicenseManager.setLicenseKey('my_key');

Then added import "'ag-grid-enterprise'" to my module file according to documentation (I'm using lazy loading modules, so I put AgGridModule not into app.module, but into that module where I need ag-grid);

Then switched rowModelType to serverSide and replaced setter with setServerSideDatasource()

I followed the documentation steps, but after grid initialization got errors listed below.

ag-Grid: could not find matching row model for rowModelType serverSide
ag-Grid: rowModelType server side is only available in ag-Grid Enterprise

I'll really appreciate for any suggestions about how to solve this problem. If anyone have some alternative/more detailed guide that would be perfect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: got same problem, any update on this?